# Rate image system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

So I've created this function where you upload an image to the server together with some information.
The text information is saved to a database while the image is saved to a folder.
Then I echo out the image together with the information that was stored in the database.
But I want to enchance it some by adding a rating system.

The rating system that I have created store the stastistics inside a txt-file.
What I need help with is to swap the saving with statistics from the txt-file and store it inside the database instead.

This is how I echo out the image, along with the information and star function:

```
<?php
//Sortering

$order = "";
if(isset($_GET['order'])){

    if($_GET['order'] == "date"){
        $order = " ORDER BY date DESC";
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['order'])){
    if($_GET['order'] == "uppladdare"){
        $order = " ORDER BY uppladdare";
    }
}
//Database connection
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("");
$selectall = "SELECT * FROM mountains $order";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $selectall);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$information =  ' Titel: ' . $row['titel'] . ' Uppladdare: ' . $row['uppladdare'] . ' Filnamn: ' . $row['filname'] . ' History: ' .$row['History'] . ' Datum: ' . $row['date']; 

//Print out correct information to the uploaded image
echo "<br>";
echo "Title: " . $row['titel'] . "<br>";
echo "Uploader: " . $row['uppladdare'] . "<br>";
echo "Imagename: " . $row['filname'] . "<br>";
echo "History: " . $row['History'] . "<br>";
echo "Date: " . $row['date'] . "<br>";
echo "Image:";
echo "<br>";
echo "<form name='rating' id='rating'>    
    <div id='rating-area' class='shadow'>   

    <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb1' data-value='1' />
    <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb2' data-value='2' />
    <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb3' data-value='3' />
    <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb4' data-value='4' />
    <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb5' data-value='5' />

    </div>


</form>";
?>
<script>
    jQuery('div#rating-area img').click(function(e){
        var val = jQuery(this).data('value') ;
        console.log(val) ;
        jQuery.post('post.php',{ rating : val },function(data,status){
            console.log('data:'+data+'/status'+status) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

</script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(function(){
     $('#resultat').load('ajax.php');

       },500);

   });
 </script>
 <?php

$original = $row['filname'];

echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='massoravbilder' href='bilder/$original'> <img src='bilder/thumb_" . $row['filname'] . "' alt='$information' /></a>" . "<br>";

}

?>
<script>
    jQuery('div#rating-area img').click(function(e){
        var val = jQuery(this).data('value') ;
        console.log(val) ;
        jQuery.post('post.php',{ rating : val },function(data,status){
            console.log('data:'+data+'/status'+status) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

</script>
```

Im still quite a beginner so I would appreciate if anyone could show me an easy way to solve this. Prefer it to be simple, like without restrictions when it comes to the vote.

Just upload each rate-onclick and echo the average of all the votes right beneath the stars.

Notes: The rating system works fine when just using textfile. ajax.php is the calculation master behind the function. And post.php sends the rating statistics to the tex-file.

Comment: On the click() function, you just have to increment the image number of rate in the database. You don't need to pass the value of rate if the increment is one. To sum up in your SQL request `image_rate = image_rate + 1`. I hope I don't miss the point.

Comment: Yes. Do not need to store rating data in the text file. Store it in the Database

Comment: I will, I have already created a database.
Looks like: 
ImageRate
ID
Rate
ImageID

But need help to connect and store in  it.

Comment: Try to achieve something and then edit your question. You just need to pass the current image id to rate in an hidden field (in your form). And then, pass it to your ajax request instead of `jQuery(this).data('value');`. In your `post.php` simply create the update request of the given image id.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Could you give me an example please?
But do I need a database or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this. I don't know if fields exist but it's the way to follow. I hope it's give you an idea.

**In your form**

```
//...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $information =  ' Titel: ' . $row['titel'] . ' Uppladdare: ' . $row['uppladdare'] . ' Filnamn: ' . $row['filname'] . ' History: ' .$row['History'] . ' Datum: ' . $row['date']; 

    //Print out correct information to the uploaded image
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Title: " . $row['titel'] . "<br>";
    echo "Uploader: " . $row['uppladdare'] . "<br>";
    echo "Imagename: " . $row['filname'] . "<br>";
    echo "History: " . $row['History'] . "<br>";
    echo "Date: " . $row['date'] . "<br>";
    echo "Image:";
    echo "<br>";

    // Add the input with image id value (I suppose it exist) 

    echo "<form name='rating' id='rating'>    
    <div id='rating-area' class='shadow'>


      <input type='hidden' name= 'image_id' value = $row[image_id]>


      <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb1' data-value='1' />
      <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb2' data-value='2' />
      <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb3' data-value='3' />
      <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb4' data-value='4' />
      <img src='stjärna.png' id='thumb5' data-value='5' />
    </div>
    </form>";
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
    jQuery('div#rating-area img').click(function(e){
        // serialize the form and retrieve all value in PHP with $_POST['theNameOfInput']
        jQuery.post('post.php',{ form : $(this).serialize() },function(data,status){
            console.log('data:'+data+'/status'+status) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

</script>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php

    $imageId = (int) $_POST['image_id'];
    // ... Your database treatments
    $sql = "UPDATE image SET image_rating = image_rating + 1 WHERE image_id = $imageId";
    //... Your code
```

Comment: The images are in a database called store "store". And each image has an ID which is PK.
So I swapped the name on all image_id and $imageID to ID 

What is the "image_rating"?
Thanks for the answer:)

Comment: It's correspond to the current rate value of your image.

Comment: I see, Im getting an error when I try to implement the code:

  <input type='hidden' name='ID' value = $row['ID']>

Shows an error on that line. But I can't really tell what's wrong.

Comment: My mistake, I guess you should remove single quote $row[ID].

Comment: The whole structure collapsed. No matter how much I reverse I can't get it to its original position.
The site that woudl be.

Comment: I made another mistake. `$(this).serialize` must be `$(this).serialize()`. (I've edited my answer).

Comment: Man, your code kind of messed up my entirer project...

http://i122.photobucket.com/albums/o277/KcMello/Ska3080rmavbild2014-04-01kl123616_zps0bfc7fef.png

Trying the last hour to fix it but nothing works. It happens after I added your code. And when I did cmd+z it still shows the same....

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be a CSS/HTML problem now. I help you for the PHP side (back end)  not the frontend. I guess you can take off the input inside the div with class shadow and put it just under the form attributes.